# Can the legal requirement to publish certain information in the newspaper be satisfied with digital publication?

Tags: united-states

I'm not sure how standard these laws are across different US states, but in Louisiana many companies are required to publish certain things in the newspaper. These are referred to as "Legals" by newspaper publishers. They include things like quarterly reports of drinking water safety infractions and board meetings.

Can a small town newspaper go fully to digital publishing while continuing to meet thr legal requirements for publishing "Legals"? Why or whynot? If so, what restrictions would apply?

Comment: Why would a newspaper have any obligation to publish "Legals" ?

Comment: @davidgo the newspaper doesnt have legal obligation to publish them, but it has an monetary obligation to publish them (its a significant portion of a newspaper's income), and the question is whether the legals, if published digitally, fulfill the legal obligations of publication.

Comment: Your question would really require legal expertise in your jurisdiction. Yes, the practice is extremely common across the US.

Comment: @TomDworzanski I'm really interested in the "common" answer in that case. Such as, for example, "In many states, such as California, the answer is no, the requirements would not be met, but this may not be the case in some states."